# Javascript functions on same DIV not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have two Ajax functions that are on the same div, the first one executes when complete page is fully loaded and call the ccslider method, instead the second one checks which menu ID I clicked, on the menu, to load dynamically different contents for different pages.

I can see the content loaded (eg: pictures) but unfortunately I don't see them in the ccslider; it seems that the slider is not executed.

But I know that works just because if I test it, removing the `swapContent()` function and place my PHP code with the MySQL query inside my main page the pictures are loaded inside the working ccslider.

Any hint on how to fix this problem?

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $('#sliding').slider({
      _Options: {
      imageWidth: 300,
      imageHeight: 200
      }
   });
});

function swapContent(cv) {
var url = "testing_cover.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: cv}, function(data) {
       $("#sliding").html(data).show();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to call the slider method again inside the swapContent() function. Try this.

```
function swapContent(cv) {
  var url = "testing_cover.php";
  $.post(url, {contentVar: cv}, function(data) {
     $("#sliding").html(data).show();
     $('#sliding').slider({
        _Options: {
        imageWidth: 300,
        imageHeight: 200
         }
     });

 });

}
```

Comment: You won a beer. I tried everything also a voodoo dance near the PC but nothing, and the solution was so easy.
Thank you very much, really HAPPY!!!! finally it works now

Answer (score 0):

I have no access to the kind of plugin you're using, but from what it seems, you're probably modifying the HTML structure needed for it's functionality. Try inserting the HTML to a wrapper inside the #sliding element as opposed to directly in it.